# Make a taxonomy column sortable in the admin?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, admin-menu, columns

I have a taxonomy term I have set to show as a column in the admin UI for my custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_asset_tax' );

function create_asset_tax() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'asset_type',
    'design_asset',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Asset Type' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'sort' => true
    )
  );
}
```

How would I make this column "sortable" in the admin UI for my custom post type?  Most of the tips I've found here seem to be for sorting columns added, not for columns that result from a taxonomy term, so it's a bit confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: So what you've done is added a custom column to your Custom Post Type containing Taxonomy Term(s) and you would like to click the column name to sort the Terms alphabetically? Or are you talking like a Filtering Dropdown?

Comment: The former (click the column in Admin to sort the terms alphabetically)

Comment: Please explain what _sorting_ is for terms which are not mutually exclusive. By default, terms are semantically unsortable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `posts_clauses` filter:

```
function wpse155797_posts_clauses( $pieces, $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $pieces;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) == 'asset_type' ) {
        if ( ( $order = strtoupper( $query->get( 'order' ) ) ) != 'DESC' ) $order = 'ASC';
        $pieces[ 'join' ] .= ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' AS tr ON ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = tr.object_id'
            . ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id'
            . ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id';
        $pieces[ 'fields' ] .= ', group_concat(t.name ORDER BY t.name ' . $order . ') AS ' . $orderby;
        $pieces[ 'groupby' ] = $wpdb->posts . '.ID';
        $pieces[ 'orderby' ] = $orderby . ' ' . $order . ', ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title ASC';
    }
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse155797_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

This assumes you've added

```
$columns['taxonomy-asset_type'] = 'asset_type';
```

to your `manage_edit_sortable_columns` filter.

This sorts by taxonomy terms but looks funny if you sort descending and have more than one term as each group still lists alphabetically. To fix this you need to override the default `'taxonomy-asset_type'` column in your `manage_posts_columns` filter to be eg `'asset_type'` (changing the `manage_edit_sortable_columns` column name above to match) and then duplicate the standard WP output code in your `manage_posts_custom_column` action with an added `array_reverse` on the output:

```
    case 'asset_type':
        $taxonomy = 'asset_type';
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy ) ) {
            $out = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
                $posts_in_term_qv = array();
                $posts_in_term_qv['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;
                $posts_in_term_qv['term'] = $t->slug;

                $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( $posts_in_term_qv, 'upload.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $t->name, $t->term_id, $taxonomy, 'display' ) )
                );
            }
            // New bit
            if ( isset( $_GET['order'] ) && $_GET['order'] == 'desc' ) {
                $out = array_reverse( $out );
            }
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            echo join( __( ', ' ), $out );
        } else {
            echo '&#8212;';
        }
        break;
```